# Change StackPanel location on a Canvas programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, stackpanel

I have stackpanel in a canvas

The stackpanel has

```
 <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
            <Slider Template="{StaticResource simpleSlider}"  x:Name="seekBar" Thumb.DragStarted="seekBar_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="seekBar_DragCompleted" Canvas.Left="347" Canvas.Top="746" Width="900" Height="2" />
            <Rectangle Height="5" />

       <StackPanel Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Right = "100">
       </StackPanel>
 </Canvas>
```

At runtime I need to change the location of the objects within the StackPanel.

Ie seekBar.Canvas.Left = 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Canvas.Left" is an example of attached dependency property. The syntax for the C# is:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(myStackPanel, 50);
```

Where myStackPanel is any custom name you must assign using x.Name in the xaml.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what's your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Canvas.SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx) and [Canvas.SetRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:** I'm assuming that by this:

> At runtime i need to change the location of the objects within the StackPanel.

You mean that you need to be able to set the `Left` position of the `StackPanel` itself (irrespective of what it contains). If this is not what you mean (for example, you don't have anything called `seekBar` in your example Xaml, even though you reference it in your code), please clarify.

---

The `Canvas` uses Attached Dependency Properties (as do other layout items, such as the `Grid`) to track layout information about contained items. Because of this, you'll either have to use the `GetLeft` and `SetLeft` functions on `Canvas`, `GetValue` and `SetValue` functions on your `StackPanel` to manipulate these values.

Do this, you'll need to give your `StackPanel` a name. I'll call it `stack`.

Given your example, you would do either this:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(stack, 50);
```

or this:

```
stack.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 50);
```

Note that the first version (`SetLeft`) is simply a wrapper around the second version, so use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of any control by `var x = btn.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));`
where btn is the control which you want the margin of.

And then use `yourstackpanel.SetValue(StackPanel.MarginProperty,new Thickness());`