# Adding an ellipse to mouse position?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add an ellipse to my grid from my mouse position. How can I define where the ellipse is drawn?

here is my mouse down event:

```
private void GridCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _sensorPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(GridCanvas);
    AddSensor();
}
```

And my AddSensor() method:

```
private void AddSensor()
{
    Ellipse sensorEllipse = new Ellipse();
    SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();


    solidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    sensorEllipse.Fill = solidColorBrush;
    sensorEllipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
    sensorEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    sensorEllipse.Width = 10;
    sensorEllipse.Height = 10;

    GridCanvas.Children.Add(sensorEllipse);
}
```

How can I add sensorEllipse where the mouse is clicked on the canvas?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818851/change-stackpanel-location-on-a-canvas-programatically).

Comment: The point from the mouse is of type Point, and I need to split these into two doubles for it to work with Canvas.SetLeft(). Do I need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set position with any of those methods:

```
private void AddSensor()
{
        Ellipse sensorEllipse = new Ellipse();
        SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

        solidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

        sensorEllipse.Fill = solidColorBrush;

        sensorEllipse.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, _sensorPoint.X);
        sensorEllipse.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, _sensorPoint.Y);

        //Canvas.SetLeft(sensorEllipse, _sensorPoint.X);
        //Canvas.SetTop(sensorEllipse, _sensorPoint.Y);

        sensorEllipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
        sensorEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        sensorEllipse.Width = 10;
        sensorEllipse.Height = 10;

        //adding event handler for right mouse down:
        sensorEllipse.MouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(sensorEllipse_MouseRightButtonDown);

        GridCanvas.Children.Add(sensorEllipse);
}
```

**EDIT**
For adding/deleting ellipses check, which mouse button was pressed at `GridCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown`

```
private void GridCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  _sensorPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(GridCanvas);
  AddSensor();
}
```

Then add event handler for new ellipses:

```
    void sensorEllipse_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = sender as Ellipse;
        GridCanvas.Children.Remove(ellipse);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

How would I go about removing them from the mouse location?

Comment: Do you want to add ellipse when user holding mouse down and remove it when he releases mouse button?

Comment: I want to add an ellipse when user left clicks (which my code does) and remove it when the user right clicks on the ellipse.

Comment: Take a look at new code - added event handler for new ellipses.