# UWP C++ self removal from canvas via EventHandler

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I have a UWP C++ app where the user can add shapes to a canvas. I want them to be able to remove them using Eraser on the Surface Pen.

Items are successfully added to the canvas like this...

```
if (e->Pointer->PointerDeviceType == Windows::Devices::Input::PointerDeviceType::Pen) {

    auto Translate = ref new TranslateTransform();
    auto ellipse = ref new Ellipse();

    PointerPoint^ p = e->GetCurrentPoint(imgCanvas);

    Translate->X = p->Position.X - Radius/2;
    Translate->Y = p->Position.Y - Radius/2;

    ellipse->Fill = ref new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper::FromArgb(127, 255, 255, 0));
    ellipse->Width = Radius;
    ellipse->Height = Radius;

    ellipse->Stroke = ref new SolidColorBrush(Colors::Black);
    ellipse->StrokeThickness = 1;

    ellipse->RenderTransform = Translate;
    ellipse->PointerPressed += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerEventHandler(this, &MainPage::onEllipseTouched);

    Canvas->Children->Append(ellipse);
}
```

I have the following function that is successfully called when touched

```
MainPage::onEllipseTouched(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    //check for eraser
    PointerPoint^ p = e->GetCurrentPoint(Canvas);
    if (p->Properties->IsEraser) {
        //NEED TO REMOVE ITSELF FROM
        //Canvas->Children->RemoveAt(i);
        //but obviously I don't know I...
    }
}
```

How do I get the ellipse to remove itself from the Child list?
The alternative method is to loop through all the Children in the canvas and calculate the closest. That doesn't sound as clean as using an EventHandler.

**EDIT**

I found this example [Adding an ellipse to mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981815/adding-an-ellipse-to-mouse-position) that also contains an example of removal exactly the way I'm trying to do it but it's in C# where the function

```
GridCanvas.Children.Remove(ellipse);
```

exists. However I can't find and equivalent in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I can't find and equivalent in C++.

It seems like `Remove()` method is not currently supported in C++. You should be able to use [`RemoveAt(UInt32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.uielementcollection#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_UIElementCollection_RemoveAt_System_UInt32_) as you tried. But you may not know the index of current ellipse, in that case you need to invoke [`IndexOf(UIElement, UInt32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UIElementCollection#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_UIElementCollection_IndexOf_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_System_UInt32__) method firstly to get the index and then you can use `RemoveAt`.Sample code as follows:

```
//Get current tapped ellipse.
Ellipse^ currentellipse = dynamic_cast<Ellipse^>(sender);
unsigned int currentindex;   
canvas->Children->IndexOf(currentellipse, &currentindex);
canvas->Children->RemoveAt(currentindex);
```

Comment: Is there any logical reason why not all methods are available in C++?
Thanks for the answer, now I need to figure out how I broke my ellipse->PointerPressed += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerEventHandler().... it's no longer working... sigh.
It. Just. Never. Ends.

Comment: @Oliver9523 For this you may need to investigation the differences between c++ and c#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b(v=vs.71).aspx .  If you you have new issues, you may open a new thread. Thanks for understanding.